# Twilio Usage Records: How to Identify / Isolate WhatsApp Only Cost?

Tags: twilio, whatsapp, twilio-api

As of February 1st, there is a new associated cost with using Twilio / Whatsapp, called  [WhatsApp Conversation](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/4409603671579-Notice-New-WhatsApp-Conversation-Based-Pricing-February-2022-).

The current [Usage Records API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/api/usage-record#usage-categories) shows only messaging category costs for inbound / outbound.

How do I identify / fetch Usage Records / Costs associated with the new pricing?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is a better question for [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact).

Comment: Thanks @philnash - already did, still waiting for an answer there too... ticket was opened on February 2nd... as of today, still no replies... :(

Comment: Do you have a ticket number? I can try to chase it up.

Comment: Yes, thanks @philnash - 7865636

Comment: It appears you were passed to the sales team? Has that happened?

Comment: I think so - the ticket has been passed around back/forth between areas/teams (per the ticket status). Do I need to have a "paid support" to have tickets answered?

Comment: If you are in communication with the sales team, then I recommend continuing to talk to them about it. You do not need paid support to have tickets answered, but this has also left the ticket for now as you have been routed to the sales team. Please let me know how you get on with them.